# How to append array to a json file which already have a array?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a name.json file having :

```
[
{"name" : "James",
 "Surname" : "Bond"
},
{
"name" : "Abc",
 "Surname" : "Xyz"
}]
```

Now I want to add another array to this existing file :

```
 [
    {"name" : "Brad",
     "Surname" : "Pitt"
    },
    {
    "name" : "Angelina ",
     "Surname" : "Jolie "
    }
 ]
```

The result should look like :

```
 [
    {"name" : "James",
     "Surname" : "Bond"
    },
    {
    "name" : "Abc",
     "Surname" : "Xyz"
    },
        {"name" : "Brad",
         "Surname" : "Pitt"
        },
        {
        "name" : "Angelina ",
         "Surname" : "Jolie "
        }
     ]
```

But i have result like :

```
[
{"name" : "James",
 "Surname" : "Bond"
},
{
"name" : "Abc",
 "Surname" : "Xyz"
}]    
  [
    {"name" : "Brad",
     "Surname" : "Pitt"
    },
    {
    "name" : "Angelina ",
     "Surname" : "Jolie "
    }
 ]
```

How to solve this issue?

I am appending data to file like this.

```
void writeJson(JSONArray jsonDataObject){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
    writer.writeValue(new File("/home/cp/name.json"), jsonDataObject);
}
```

Comment: Post the code here

Comment: Well, don't insert brackets in your text editor. Or did you by any chance used an IDE and programmed something? Because we don't know.

Comment: Thing is, i want to append JSONArry every time to file on disk and i am using eclipse.

Comment: see also [Optimized way of writing/reading json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63103100/optimized-way-of-writing-reading-json-file)

Answer (score 2):

The one **reasonable** way here:

1. Use any of the plenty JSON parsers around to **read** the JSON file
2. This will result in an in-memory representation of that array
3. Add the additional elements to that array
4. Use another library to **write** the whole content into a new file

EDIT; given your comment on huge volume:

Well, then I would be looking into distributing the whole processing.

And beyond that I would also look into your overall requirements:

A) why does your data show up like this? If you know that things should go into **one** JSON array; can't you change your "input processing" to build that thing immediately?

B) Or the other way round - can't your change your "follow up" process to understand that data doesn't come in one, but in several JSON array files?

In other words: your requirement seems to be "all records must be within one single JSON array (file)". Can't you change that to: "records are coming in JSON array (file)s; and there is a **list** that keeps track of all those array files and their order?!

Comment: I am writing JSONArray 5000 times  having 1000 objects in each JSONArray. Final size of file is about 10 GB(10 mil. Records).

Comment: I see. I put in an update to my answer; hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using your favorite JSON library (I'll use json.org for this example):

```
JSONArray fullJsonArray = new JSONArray();

JSONArray list1 = JSONArray.fromObject(jsonString1);
JSONArray list2 = JSONArray.fromObject(jsonString2);

jsonArray.addAll(list1.toCollection());
jsonArray.addAll(list2.toCollection());
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you are using Jackson, consider the following solution:

```java
// First JSON
String json1 = "[{\"name\":\"James\",\"Surname\":\"Bond\"}," 
             + "{\"name\":\"Abc\",\"Surname\":\"Xyz\"}]";

// Second JSON
String json2 = "[{\"name\":\"Brad\",\"Surname\":\"Pitt\"}," 
             + "{\"name\":\"Angelina \",\"Surname\":\"Jolie\"}]";

// Create ObjectMapper instance to manipulate JSON
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// Parse the JSON strings into the Jackson tree model
JsonNode tree1 = mapper.readTree(json1);
JsonNode tree2 = mapper.readTree(json2);

// Append the second tree to the first tree
((ArrayNode) tree1).addAll((ArrayNode) tree2);

// Serialize the tree into a string
String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(tree1);
```

It will produce the following result:

```java
[ {
  "name" : "James",
  "Surname" : "Bond"
}, {
  "name" : "Abc",
  "Surname" : "Xyz"
}, {
  "name" : "Brad",
  "Surname" : "Pitt"
}, {
  "name" : "Angelina ",
  "Surname" : "Jolie"
} ]
```